# ProxyRemote leads to "AH00898: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server ...", works on other server

Tags: apache, proxy, openssl, mod-proxy, mod-ssl

## Goal

Set up a Virtual Host as Reverse Proxy, which also acts as Forward Proxy to another "Remote" Proxy for a specific URL pattern.

## Issue

I have 2 servers (actually 2 separate machines), both having the same config but **only one server is able to forward the requests**.

I've searched the whole web and did even more experiments than described below (but seem irrelevant to mention here), so I'm very very thankful for any idea/experiment you come up with!

## Config

### Dump

Acc. to `apache2ctl -DDUMP_CONFIG | grep -vE "^[ ]*#[ ]*[0-9]+:$" > apache_dump.conf` the apache config of both servers is **identical**.

### Virtual Host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

[...]

SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyRemote "https://booking-service.com/" "http://remote-proxy:3128"

<Location /booking>
    ProxyPass https://booking-service.com/api
    ProxyPassReverse https://booking-service.com/api
    ProxyPreserveHost Off
    RequestHeader set X-Api-Key "..."
    RequestHeader unset Cookie
    RequestHeader unset Authorization
</Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

### Modules

Here an excerpt of activated modules which IMHO might be relevant:

```
[...]
http_module (static)
[...]
ssl_module (shared)
[...]
proxy_module (shared)
proxy_http_module (shared)
proxy_ftp_module (shared)
proxy_ajp_module (shared)
proxy_wstunnel_module (shared)
proxy_balancer_module (shared)
[...]
```

## Regular Error Logs

(IPs and host names obfuscated)

```
[proxy:trace2] [pid 21616:tid 140692231767808] proxy_util.c(3016): HTTPS: fam 2 socket created to connect to booking-service.com
[proxy:debug] [pid 21616:tid 140692231767808] proxy_util.c(3050): AH02824: HTTPS: connection established with 192.18.191.131:3128 (booking-service.com)
[proxy:debug] [pid 21616:tid 140692231767808] proxy_util.c(2677): AH00948: CONNECT: sending the CONNECT request for booking-service.com:443 to the remote proxy 192.18.191.131:3128 (remote-proxy.net)
[proxy:debug] [pid 21616:tid 140692231767808] proxy_util.c(2731): AH00949: send_http_connect: response from the forward proxy: HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established\r\n\r\n
[proxy:debug] [pid 21616:tid 140692231767808] proxy_util.c(3218): AH00962: HTTPS: connection complete to 192.18.191.131:3128 (remote-proxy.net)
[proxy:error] [pid 21616:tid 140692231767808] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): [client 111.222.33.444:20435] AH01084: pass request body failed to 192.18.191.131:3128 (remote-proxy.net)
[proxy:error] [pid 21616:tid 140692231767808] [client 111.222.33.444:20435] AH00898: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server returned by /booking/test-request
[proxy_http:error] [pid 21616:tid 140692231767808] [client 111.222.33.444:20435] AH01097: pass request body failed to 192.18.191.131:3128 (remote-proxy.net) from 111.222.33.444 ()
[proxy:debug] [pid 21616:tid 140692231767808] proxy_util.c(2334): AH00943: HTTPS: has released connection for (booking-service.com)
```

## Error Logs With ssl:trace7

I get the following for both web servers:

```
[ssl:trace3] [pid 25298:tid 140395937773312] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2180): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] OpenSSL: Handshake: start
[...]
[ssl:trace3] [pid 25298:tid 140395937773312] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2189): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] OpenSSL: Loop: before/connect initialization
[ssl:trace4] [pid 25298:tid 140395937773312] ssl_engine_io.c(2214): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] OpenSSL: write 517/517 bytes to BIO#7fb05c009ba0 [mem: 7fb05c011070] (BIO dump follows)
[ssl:trace7] [pid 25298:tid 140395937773312] ssl_engine_io.c(2137): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[ssl:trace7] [pid 25298:tid 140395937773312] ssl_engine_io.c(2175): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] | 0000: 16 03 01 02 00 01 00 01-fc 03 03 c5 c2 b9 30 65  ..............0e |
[...]
[ssl:trace7] [pid 25298:tid 140395937773312] ssl_engine_io.c(2175): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] | 0140: 03 00 0f 00 01 01 00 15-00 bb                    ..........       |
[ssl:trace7] [pid 25298:tid 140395937773312] ssl_engine_io.c(2179): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] | 0517 - <SPACES/NULS>
[ssl:trace7] [pid 25298:tid 140395937773312] ssl_engine_io.c(2181): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[ssl:trace3] [pid 25298:tid 140395937773312] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2189): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
[ssl:trace4] [pid 25298:tid 140395937773312] ssl_engine_io.c(2214): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] OpenSSL: read 7/7 bytes from BIO#7fb05c00cc70 [mem: 7fb05c0165d0] (BIO dump follows)
[ssl:trace7] [pid 25298:tid 140395937773312] ssl_engine_io.c(2137): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[ssl:trace7] [pid 25298:tid 140395937773312] ssl_engine_io.c(2175): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] | 0000: 16 03 03 00 41 02                                ....A.           |
[ssl:trace7] [pid 25298:tid 140395937773312] ssl_engine_io.c(2179): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] | 0007 - <SPACES/NULS>
[ssl:trace7] [pid 25298:tid 140395937773312] ssl_engine_io.c(2181): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[ssl:trace4] [pid 25298:tid 140395937773312] ssl_engine_io.c(2214): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] OpenSSL: read 63/63 bytes from BIO#7fb05c00cc70 [mem: 7fb05c0165da] (BIO dump follows)
[ssl:trace7] [pid 25298:tid 140395937773312] ssl_engine_io.c(2137): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[ssl:trace7] [pid 25298:tid 140395937773312] ssl_engine_io.c(2175): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] | 0000: 00 3d 03 03 f8 86 f8 5b-c5 71 0e 3f d6 fb 37 1d  .=.....[.q.?..7. |
[...]
[ssl:trace7] [pid 25298:tid 140395937773312] ssl_engine_io.c(2175): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] | 0030: 00 00 00 00 0b 00 04 03-00 01 02 00 23           ............#    |
[ssl:trace7] [pid 25298:tid 140395937773312] ssl_engine_io.c(2179): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] | 0063 - <SPACES/NULS>
[ssl:trace7] [pid 25298:tid 140395937773312] ssl_engine_io.c(2181): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[ssl:trace3] [pid 25298:tid 140395937773312] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2189): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] OpenSSL: Loop: unknown state
[ssl:trace4] [pid 25298:tid 140395937773312] ssl_engine_io.c(2214): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] OpenSSL: read 5/5 bytes from BIO#7fb05c00cc70 [mem: 7fb05c026da3] (BIO dump follows)
[ssl:trace7] [pid 25298:tid 140395937773312] ssl_engine_io.c(2137): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[ssl:trace7] [pid 25298:tid 140395937773312] ssl_engine_io.c(2175): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] | 0000: 16 03 03 0d ce                                   .....            |
[ssl:trace7] [pid 25298:tid 140395937773312] ssl_engine_io.c(2181): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[ssl:trace4] [pid 25298:tid 140395937773312] ssl_engine_io.c(2214): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] OpenSSL: read 3534/3534 bytes from BIO#7fb05c00cc70 [mem: 7fb05c026da8] (BIO dump follows)
[ssl:trace7] [pid 25298:tid 140395937773312] ssl_engine_io.c(2137): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[ssl:trace7] [pid 25298:tid 140395937773312] ssl_engine_io.c(2175): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] | 0000: 0b 00 0d ca 00 0d c7 00-07 12 30 82 07 0e 30 82  ..........0...0. |
[...]
[ssl:trace7] [pid 25298:tid 140395937773312] ssl_engine_io.c(2175): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] | 0dc0: ca 5b e0 d5 f6 6c 23 9d-20 29 55 cd 3a c5        .[...l#. )U.:.   |
[ssl:trace7] [pid 25298:tid 140395937773312] ssl_engine_io.c(2181): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The **BAD** web server does abruptly stop here, there is no "Certificate Verification" and no "Handshake: done", i.e. no further `ssl:...` log entries related to this client request.

In contrast, the **GOOD** web server does the following:

```
[ssl:debug] [pid 9659:tid 140475999237888] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1738): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] AH02275: Certificate Verification, depth 1, CRL checking mode: none (0) [subject: CN=...]
[ssl:debug] [pid 9659:tid 140475999237888] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1738): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] AH02275: Certificate Verification, depth 0, CRL checking mode: none (0) [subject: CN=...]
[...]
[ssl:trace3] [pid 9659:tid 140475999237888] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2184): [remote 192.18.191.131:3128] OpenSSL: Handshake: done
[...]
```

## Failed Experiments

What I tried so far:

- Adding the following settings (even if the other web server works w/o them, i know... I'm desperate :D):

```
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1
SSLProxyCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/<the-ca-cert>.crt [afaik should be considered anyway b/c in /etc/ssl/certs]
```

- Restarting the apache2.service
- Restarting the whole linux machine
- Request with **curl: works**!

  - `curl --request POST 'https://booking-service.com/api/test-request' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'X-Api-Key: ...' --proxy 'http://remote-proxy.net:3128' --data '@/tmp/request-body.txt' -iv`
- Debug with openssl: looks good & is the same for both servers

  - `openssl-1_1 s_client -connect booking-service.com -proxy remote-proxy.net:3128 -state -debug`

## App Versions (identical on both servers)

- Linux: `lsb_release -a`:

```
LSB Version:    n/a
Distributor ID: SUSE
Description:    SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP5
Release:        12.5
Codename:       n/a
```

- Apache: `httpd -v`:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.38 (Linux/SUSE)
Server built:   2019-02-08 01:59:10.000000000 +0000
```

- OpenSSL: `openssl version`:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.2p-fips  14 Aug 2018
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check that the TLS/SSL certificates are the same in all server.

By default httpd is generating a self signed certificate in each  installation.

It is imperative that all servers/hosts in TLS communication cluster share identical certificates in order to trust each other.

I suggest to copy private key, and public certificate from host #1 to other hosts.

Comment: Thx for the idea! But certs are the same on both servers. Checked the relevant  cert directories & also analyzed/confirmed with curl & openssl (just added this info to the question as well). So if curl works, I assume that in apache there is a specific setting defined which enforces mod_ssl to use openssl in a way that curl does not - but then again I remember that the apache config dumps of both web servers are equal, so there shouldn't be any differences in apache settings!?